# Permutation test for paired data using a for loop

Tags: r, permutation

I want to permutate my data, which is paired, using a for loop. I think I'm supposed to randomly flip some of my pairs in this case, but I can't figure out how to do that exactly. I already searched the internet for this, and I found ways to permutate this kind of data, but I didn't find it for this kind of method. An example of what I think I'm supposed to do:

Example dataset:

```r
   day1   day2
 1  5.5   1.5  
 2  2.5   6.5  
 3  7.5   8.5  
 4  4.5   1.5  
 5  5.5   1.5
```

and I want it to randomly swap some of the rows, for example this:

```
   day1   day2
 1  5.5   1.5  
 2  6.5   2.5 
 3  7.5   8.5  
 4  1.5   4.5  
 5  5.5   1.5
```

I've tried using the sample() command, but that seems to swap the whole rows instead of only some of them. So how do you randomly swap some of them?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to randomly swap the columns of certain rows try :

```
set.seed(6781)
replace_inds <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df[replace_inds, ] <- df[replace_inds, 2:1]
df

#  day1 day2
#1  5.5  1.5
#2  2.5  6.5
#3  8.5  7.5
#4  4.5  1.5
#5  1.5  5.5
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(day1 = c(5.5, 2.5, 7.5, 4.5, 5.5), day2 = c(1.5, 
6.5, 8.5, 1.5, 1.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner option that will shuffle elements in the first and second columns. It will also work if there are several columns to swap:

```r
setNames(as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, sample))), names(df))
#>   day1 day2
#> 1  1.5  5.5
#> 2  2.5  6.5
#> 3  8.5  7.5
#> 4  4.5  1.5
#> 5  5.5  1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pmap` from `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   pmap_dfr(~ sample(c(...)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#   day2  day1
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1   1.5   5.5
#2   6.5   2.5
#3   8.5   7.5
#4   1.5   4.5
#5   1.5   5.5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(day1 = c(5.5, 2.5, 7.5, 4.5, 5.5), day2 = c(1.5, 
6.5, 8.5, 1.5, 1.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```